# Where can I find usernames and passwords of extensions I bought

Tags: magento2

where are all login credentials of extensions stored in Magento 2.

can't seem to find them.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know which extensions You've purchased? If you connected to Magento Marketplace to your store, you should be able to find the extensions through the marketplace. Each company has its own website with login credentials.

For instance [Webkul store](https://store.webkul.com) or [Amasty](https://amasty.com) is one of the examples.

Hope this helps!